# pgsql: Select different unique columns with newest timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group

I have a psql table with columns: write_date, tagwaarde, tagnaam, tagkwaliteit, schrijven.
What I need to do now is to retrieve only the newest unique value for each column where "schrijven" is true.

Hard to explain so here is an example:
[image]

In this case I want this output:

```
[('Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT0', 777), ('Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT8', 0)]
```

Because:

Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT0 = 777 and Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT0 = 666

=> 777 has the newest timestamp

I have tried `SELECT tagnaam, tagwaarde FROM inlezen WHERE schrijven = True ORDER BY write_date DESC LIMIT 1`

This gives just

```
[('Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT8', 0)]
```

as output.

I have tried some things with DISTINCT but I couldn't get it to work.

What would be the right way to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should put sample data and desired results *into* the question.  If the external link fails, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, didn't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: . . Actually, you do.  The OP can always modify the question with additional text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with Postgres' [`distinct on ()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) operator:

```
SELECT distinct on (tagnaam) tagnaam, tagwaarde 
FROM inlezen 
WHERE schrijven = True 
ORDER BY tagnaam, write_date DESC
```

If you prefer a standard ANSI SQL solution, then this can be done using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select tagnaam, tagwaarde
from (
    SELECT tagnaam, tagwaarde, 
           row_number() over (partition by tagnaam order by write_date DESC) as rn
    FROM inlezen 
    WHERE schrijven = True 
) t
where rn = 1
order by tagnaam;
```

The `distinct on` is usually faster than the solution with the window function.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the "most recent one" can always be expressed in terms of *there does not exist a more recent one* :

```
SELECT tagnaam, tagwaarde 
FROM inlezen lz
WHERE lz.schrijven = True
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM inlezen nx
        WHERE nx.tagnaam = lz.tagnaam
        AND nx.schrijven = True
        AND nx.write_date > lz.write_date
        );
```

Comment: Which is most of the time a lot slower than a `distinct on` or a solution with a window function.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however a_horse_with_no_name's solution seems to be more elegant and shorter.